# convert full page to image

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I tried to find a way to transfer a full page to an image.

I am Using angular 6 + typescript.

Found similar question asked before but everyone pushing to use html2canvas.

Is there a way to do it without using experimental libraries like html2canvas?

I prefer not to use external libraries at all if possible.

what come out in window.print() is perfect, is there a way to use it?

Element that i want to transfer to image then i will send it to a webapi server:

```
<div class="page-wrapper" id="orderPage">
<br>
<div>
    <br>
    <h2 class="center font-weight-bold">Title</h2>
    <br>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isLoaded">Loading...</div>
<div *ngIf="isLoaded">
    <table class="font-weight-bold">
        <tr>
            <td class="table-50">
                <div class="right">Full Name</div>
                <span class="block padding-right-10">
                    <input class="input-100 right" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Insert Name">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="table-50">
                <div class="right">Phone:</div>
                <span class="block padding-right-10">
                    <input class="input-100 right" type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Insert Phone">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if you can do it on the server then taking a screenshot might be better. with puppeteer for example. you can have the whole page screenshot, also supports pdf

Comment: the server can add and attach the picture to the order so i need create image client side.
right now the user print to image than upload it manually, just want to make it easier for the user.